# Firefox sync API - does it exist?

Tags: firefox, synchronization, mozilla

Does FireFox sync have API? Is it working these days? Is there  documentation? I've searched for it but barely found something usefull.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.services.mozilla.com/sync/ looks comprehensive enough and I think it's up to date (the last commit on the [repo](https://github.com/mozilla-services/docs) is 8 days old).
A Python client is available on GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncclient.

There's also a Sync to Kinto bridge, to use the Kinto interface to access the Sync data: https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncto